# Installing instrument-control package for octave on raspbian

Tags: unix, octave, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

i have got a problem when i wan to install instrument-control package on raspbian (i am using raspberry pi 3b+) in octave 4.4.1. I tried to install it on other version of octave but it didnt work. I tried to do the same on ubuntu mate but i can't too. There was other probles that i didnt know how to solve. I tried many ideas of solving this problem ex. pkg install -forge instrument-control (when i write this into octave it makes my pi turn of after a few minutes), other solutions like deleting vix11 in src in octave folders didnt work too, many many others which didnt work i dont even remember (trying to solve it since 3 days). I have to install this package because i want to use serial function to send some information using spi to my stm. Using pkg install path_of_instrument-control_package didnt help. I have used many versions of instrument control but nothing helps.

Comment: Until now you are just writing that "it doesn't work". Crying how traumatic this is doesn't help. You have to show your error if there is one and describe what you expect and how your expectation isn't fulfilled.

Comment: I want to have instrument-control package installed, when i tried to raspberry turning off, how can i tell you what error it outputs if it turning off? When package is installed it returns "For information about changes from previous versions of "name_of_package" run 'news name_of_package'.

Comment: what means "when i tried to raspberry turning off"? You said you've tried Ubuntu Mate, was this on a PC?

Comment: If your main problem ist, that your raspberry stops working: this is typically a problem with a weak power supply or overheating. Please amke sure and double check, that your power supply is sufficient and monitor the cpu temperature while compiling

Comment: When i tried to install instrument-control package on raspbian on raspberry pi 3b+ it(raspberry) turns off. Ubuntu mate was installed on raspberry pi before, now i am using raspbian, because with mate were problems with 'cannot find make' while installing this package.

Comment: Since i wrote pkg install -forge instrument-control passed around 20 minutes and pi is working, nothing more displayed, it is lagged, but responses when i use mouse, is it possible that it must last so long to install this package? Other packages were much faster around seconds.

Comment: If you install a package via -force, the sourcode is downloaded, compiled and linked. This is why you need make, g++ and all the other stuff. If you install it via apt, the binary release is installed

Comment: Have you understand this? If you are running buster just do `sudo apt install octave-instrument-control`